# Enabling Developer Mode fails with error code 0x80004005

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to install Ubuntu bash shell (Windows Subsystem for Unix) on Windows 10 Enterprise. To do this I need to enable Developer Mode in System Config. It fails with the following error:

> Enabling Developer Mode fails with error code 0x80004005

I found the following [MSDN article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a7e94e5b-db19-492f-a1c1-d5fa3aa87d0d/enabling-developer-mode-fails-with-error-code-0x80004005?forum=Win10SDKToolsIssues) but it still fails with the error:

> [SC] OpenService FAILED 1060:
>
> The specified service does not exist as an installed service.

Anyone know how to get past this?

Answer (score 0):

Wow! Turns out even though it gives an error it actually works.

¯\_(ツ)_/¯